# Programmatically open webpage from file and click link to handle response C#

Tags: c#, html, .net, hyperlink, click

The scenario is that a mail is sent to an inbox. Attached to the mail is a html file which the user clicks to open the page in a browser. They then click a link on the webpage which opens a PDF file online.

Now, what I want to achieve programmatically with c# is to save the attached html file on disk, open the file, find the link, click it and save the file that opens to disk.

I have gotten as far as programmatically open the email and save the attached html file to disk. But now I'm sort of stuck at opening the file programmatically.
I've gotten as far as creating a FileWebRequest to open the file but I don't know how to find the link ("a" tag, only on in the whole page) and programmatically click it (in c#) so the PDF opens so I can download it and save to disk.

What needs to be done after the filewebrequest?

```
FileWebRequest req = (FileWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(pathToHtmlFile);
FileWebResponse res = (FileWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
// What now..?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you should extract the PDF URL using RegEx from html content and then download it using WebClient :

```
    private static string FindPdfFileDownloadLink(string htmlContent)
    {
        return Regex.Match(htmlContent, @"^(https?:\/\/)?www\.([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})\/[\w \.-]+?\.pdf$").Value;
    }

    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        string htmlContent = File.ReadAllText("1.html");
        string pdfUrl = FindPdfFileDownloadLink(htmlContent);

        using (WebClient wClient = new WebClient())
        {
            wClient.DownloadFile(pdfUrl, @"1.pdf");
        }

        Console.Read();
        return 0;
    }
```

if you want to really click on link for any reason you can load the html in a hidden web browser and find the element that you want and click on it.

To load the content into WebBrowser control :

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(@"1.html");
```

and to find and click on element :

```
HtmlElement link = webBrowser.Document.GetElementByID("link_id_58547")
link.InvokeMember("Click")
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but I need to click the link because there is a javscript attached to the onclick which opens the pdf. There is no link to the PDF in the href so to speak but instead the link looks like this: <a
href="57057.pdf?sn=NTcwNTcucGRm" onclick="return __(this)" target=_blank>57057.pdf</a>